# Calculate the integral, with the help of Euler's integral

Tags: integration

Calculate the follwing integral:

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{x+2x^3+x^5}}dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share your thoughts and what you have tried? Regards

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
x+2x^3+x^5 = x(1+x^2)^2
$$
Now find a substitution based on this that makes the integral look more like the Beta function.

---

Substitute $x=\sqrt{u}$, giving
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-u}{(1+u)^2}}\frac{du}{2u^{3/4}} = \frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-u}}{(1+u)u^{3/4}}du
$$
You will notice that this is already quite close to being in the form of the Beta function. From here, you can use a taylor series on $\frac1{1+u}$ (which will converge correctly for all points in the integral) to get a sum of beta functions. This is how one would calculate it using Euler's Beta function.

It can be integrated directly to obtain a beta function, but this requires some more clever work. Let $\frac{1-x^2}{x}=2A^2$, so $x=\frac{\sqrt{A^4+4}-A^2}{2}$ and $\frac{dx}{1+x^2} = -\frac{2A}{A^4+4}dA$

$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{x}}\frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \sqrt{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{A^2}{A^4+1}dA
$$
Now, let $A^4=B$, so $A=\sqrt[4]{B}$ and $dA=\frac{dB}{4B^{3/4}}$, giving
$$
\sqrt{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{B+1}\frac{dB}{4B^{1/4}}
$$
Now, let $B=\frac1C-1$, do $dB=-\frac{dC}{C^2}$. This gives
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2}\int_0^1 \frac{C}{4(\frac1C-1)^{1/4}}\frac{dC}{C^2}&=\sqrt{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{4(1-C)^{1/4}C^{3/4}}dC\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{3/2}}B(\frac14,\frac34)
\end{align}
And if you look into it, $B(\frac14,\frac34)=\sqrt{2}\pi$. Therefore, the integral is equal to $\frac\pi2$ (which can be verified by numerical integration).

Note: the overall substitution works out to be $\frac{1-x^2}{x}=2\sqrt{\frac{1-C}C}$, or $x=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-C}}{\sqrt{C}}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have any method (or way) to solve this problem ! Again, thank you for your help .

Comment: Can you solve by Using the beta function method.  Beta is defined by $$B(p,q)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-1}dx$$ Or  Using the Gamma function method $$\Gamma(n) = \int_{0 }^{ + \infty } x^{n-1} e^{- x}dx$$

Comment: It has to be the beta function, because the integral you're looking at doesn't have an exponential in it... but I'll add a little more detail to help you get there.

Comment: Ok, Please solve this problem by your method ! (any method ). Thank a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you can relate this integral to the beta function?

Comment: I think that It can solve by  beta function or Gamma function or both. May be I'm wrong . So please post your solution . Thank you.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: At the very least, you can do so via a single application of a taylor series - you get a tidy sum of beta functions.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: As it turns out, it can be reduced to a beta function. It's a lot longer than I thought it would be, though.

Comment: @GlenO: (+1) Nice answer.

Comment: I got the answer $\pi/2$, but with a different technique.

Comment: Dear Mhenni Benghorbal, Can you post your solution?